# Check for element visibility

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to unit test this chunk:

```
<div className={classnames('loader-text', { 'loader-text-show': showText })} data-testid="loader-text" >
        LOADING...
</div>
```

css:

```
.loader {
  &-text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
  }
  &-text-show {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I manage the visibility of the text via `loader-text-show` css class, which is added after 5 seconds, therefore the "LOADING..." text is there, but has `opacity:0` at first.

I want to first check that the text is hidden then, after 5 seconds, it is visible.
I used to check the presence of the class `loader-text-show`, but now it seems the Testing library is discouraging [this approach](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#manual-queries).
I've tried different solutions, but none of them works.

This fails on `not.toBeVisible()` assertion because the `div` itself is visible, even if the text is not visible. That's not a very logical behaviour in my hopinion...

```
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { container, getByText } = render(<Loader large />);
    expect(screen.queryByText("LOADING...")).not.toBeVisible();
    act(() => {
         jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
    });
    expect(screen.queryByText('LOADING...')).toBeVisible();
```